# Which is grammatical - "There is a sign {reading / reads / which reads / that reads / to read}"?

Tags: word-choice

- ***There's a sign reading "No Entry"***.
- ***There's a sign reads "No Entry"***.
- ***There's a sign which reads "No Entry"***.
- ***There's a sign that reads "No Entry"***.
- ***There's a sign to read "No Entry"***.

Which one is right? I'm quite confused about the usage of these tenses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic sentence is "There is a sign." You then need a modifier and there are two choices. You can either use a participle:

> There's a sign reading "No Entry".

Or a relative clause

> There's a sign that reads "No entry".
>   There's a sign which reads "No entry".

The second option is not grammatical (though learn about relative clauses without a pronoun)

The last gives purpose of the object, which is not the meaning you want. Compare with:

> I use my glasses to read the newspaper.

Comment: Nice explanation; +1. I'd like to add that #2 would be okay, if in the form: _There's a sign **and it reads** "No Entry"._

Comment: What do you mean by "the second option is not grammatical"?

Comment: I mean "There's a sign reads "no entry"" does not follow the "rules" of English syntax.

Answer (score 1):

1, 3 and 4 are grammatically correct. 2 and 5 are not. But generally signs, in BrE at least, don't "read": they "say", as in "There's a sign saying 'No Entry'".

Comment: Not sure I agree. "The sign reads..." seems fine to me. (native Br Eng speaker)